# partial derivative of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=\sin\left(z+\mathrm{e}^{3z}\right)$. Find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}(z)$.

I tried to start with the well known result
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}=4\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right).$$
Am I right to use this? Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$
\newcommand{\i}{i\,}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathcal R}
\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal I}
\newcommand{\l}{\left(}
\newcommand{\r}{\right)}
\newcommand{\z}{\overline{z}}
\newcommand{\xy}{x + \i y}
\newcommand{\y}{\i y}
\newcommand{\x}{x}
\newcommand{\e}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{\,#1}}
\newcommand{\u}{\Big(\!\sin x \cos\l\e{3z}\r+\cos x \sin\l\e{3z}\r\!\Big)\cosh y}
\newcommand{\v}{\Big(\!\cos x\cosh\l\e{3z}\r-\sin x\sinh\l\e{3z}\r\!\Big)\sinh y}
$
**HINT**: Represent your complex-value function $f$ as in terms of real and imaginary components.

---

Recall that  complex derivatives with respect to $z = x + \i y$ and $\z = x - \i y$ are defined as:
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial z} =
\frac{1}{2}\left(
  \frac{\partial }{\partial x}- \i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\right), 
\quad 
\frac{\partial }{\partial \z} =
\frac{1}{2}\left(
  \frac{\partial }{\partial x} + \i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}
\right).
$$

Indeed,
$$
\begin{cases}
 z = x + \i y, \\ 
\z = x - \i y
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
x = \frac{1}{2}\l z + \z\r , \\ 
y = \frac{1}{2i}\l z - \z\r
\end{cases}
\implies 
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{z}} = \frac{1}{2}, &
\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{\z}} = \frac{1}{2}, \\
\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{z}} = \frac{1}{2i}, &
\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{\z}} = -\frac{1}{2i}. \\
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\z}} = 
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{\z}} + \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{\z}} = 
\frac{1}{2}\bigg(
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} + \i\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}
\bigg)
$$

---

Any complex function $\ f:\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$  can be written as 
$$
f\left(z\right) = f\left(x,y\right) = u\left(x,y\right) + \i v\left(x,y\right),
$$
where $u = \Re\left(f\right)$ and $v = \Im\left(f\right)$ are real functions which are  real and imaginary components of $f$ respectively.
For your specific case $\, f\left(z\right)=\sin\left(z+\mathrm{e}^{3z}\right)\,$ the real and imaginary components  $u$ and $v$ can be computed as following:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sin z & = \sin\l\xy\r = \sin\l x\r \cos\l \y\r + \cos\l x\r\sin\l \y\r = 
\\ & = \sin x \cosh y + \i \cos x \sinh y,
\\
\e{z} & = \e{\xy} = \e x \big(\cos y +\i \sin y \big),
\\
z + \e{3z} & =  \xy + \e{3x} \big(\cos y +\i \sin y \big) = 
x \e{3x}  \cos y + \i \l y+\e{3x}\sin y \r.
\end{aligned}
$$
Denoting $\ \R  := x \e{3x}  \cos y$ and $\I  := y+\e{3x}\sin y, \,$ we write
$$
\begin{aligned}
f\l z\r & = f \big(\R+\i\I\big) = \sin \big(\R+\i\I\big) = 
\underbrace{\sin \R \cosh\I}_{:=u} + \i
\underbrace{\cos\R\sinh\I}_{:=v}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore 
$$
f\l z \r = f\l \xy\r = u\l x, y \r + \i v\l x, y \r,\ \ \text{where} \ \ \ 
\begin{cases}
u \l x, y \r = \sin \l x \e{3x}  \cos y\r \cosh \l y+\e{3x}\sin y\r
\\
v \l x, y \r = \cos\l x \e{3x}  \cos y\r \sinh \l y+\e{3x}\sin y\r
\end{cases}
$$
Finally, we write 
$$
\bbox[5pt, border:2pt solid #FF0000]{\ 
f\l x,y\r = 
\sin \l x \e{3x}\!  \cos y\r \cosh \l y+\!\e{3x}\!\sin y\r + \i
\cos\l x \e{3x}\!  \cos y\r \sinh \l y+\!\e{3x}\!\sin y\r\ 
}
$$

---

I hope you can pick it from here and compute the derivative 
$$
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\z}} = \frac{1}{2}\bigg(
\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} + \i\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}
\bigg)
$$

Comment: There are (unsurprisingly) typos in your formula for $f$. Would you *honestly* suggest expansion in real and imaginary parts is a good way to solve this? It seems like time not very well-spent.

Comment: The point of Vlad's answer is to show what's going on "under the hood" when people take partial derivatives with respect to the complex numbers $z$ and $z^*$.  After all, $z$ and $z^*$ are not independent of each other in the naive sense; the value of one completely determines the value of the other.

Comment: Once the student learns the restricted sense in which they can treat them as independent number (i.e., because $\partial_z z^* = 0=\partial_{z^*} z$ and $\partial_z z = 1 =\partial_{z^*} z^*$, where $\partial_z$ and $\partial_{z^*}$ are defined as above), the student can perform the computation quickly by forgetting about the real and imaginary parts $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 7):

Your $f$ is a composition of holomorphic functions, so is itself holomorphic. Hence
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar z} = 0.
$$
(This is just Cauchy-Riemanns' equations in disguise.)

Comment: mrf ..thanks a lot..

Answer (score 6):

I think you are misunderstanding the question (but I might misunderstand it as well). You are probably asked to compute the Wirtinger derivative
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}} = \frac12 \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \mathrm{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right). \tag{1}
$$
Hence you should write $f(z)$ as $f(x,y)$ where $x = \Re z$ and $y = \Im z$. Then you should differentiate with respect to $x$ and $y$ and insert them into (1).